# TableView open url

Tags: swift

i have code to load results returned from an api `https://api.myjson.com/bins/oe3gu` :

```
let url = URL(string:"https://api.myjson.com/bins/oe3gu")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {
            data, responese, error in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
            } else {
                if let dataContent = data {
                    do {
                        let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
                        print(result)

                    } catch {
                        print("Json Faild")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
```

How can i put title in cell label in tableView and then when i click on the cell I want to open the url in browser

Comment: What research have you done, this looks like something that has been done many times before?

Answer (score 0):

use usual code for TVCell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: REUSE_ID, for: indexPath) as! TripTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...        
    let row = indexPath.row
    // take a part fo url.. 
    let title = ...[row]
    cell.textLabel.text = title
```

....

You can for example:

..
url = URL(string:"https://api.myjson.com/bins/oe3gu")

let title = url.lastPathComponent

if "oe3gu" is enough.

I will prefer:

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
typealias InfoTuple = (String,String)

let myInfo :[InfoTuple] = [
    ("https://api.myjson.com/bins/oe3gu" , "link 1"),
    ("https://api.myjson.com/bins/oe3gu2" , "link 2"),
    ("https://api.myjson.com/bins/oe3gu2" , "link 3"),
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}


// MARK: - Table view data source


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myInfo.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...
    let row = indexPath.row
    let (title, _) = myInfo[row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = title
    return cell
}
```

....

and your code will be:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let row = indexPath.row
    let (_, url) = myInfo[row]

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {
        data, responese, error in
        .....
}
```